# Developing traditional style webapps with GWT

Tags: java, gwt

In many JVM web frameworks survies and Indeed.com trends graphs, GWT looks to be the most (or among the top) popular JVM framework.
But AFAIK, GWT excels when the application is one page app -to some degree of course- (like GMail, Google Reader ..)

Does this mean that new developed Java webapps are one page apps mainly (not traditional request-new page response)?
Is it possible to develop SpringMVC or Struts2 style webapps with GWT? or it is not recommended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely, it is definitely possible to build struts apps with GWT; at some level all the GWT is, is a convenient way of writing javascript (in my perl days, we called it 'syntactic sugar').

You can still use GWT-RPC, JSON, or HTML forms to communicate with the server.

You can attach to any arbitrary HTML element using `RootPanel.get("id");` to add javascript widgets.

Almost every javascripty component on my employer's website is written in GWT: http://www.cohomefinder.com/ .  The backend is an old fork of struts.

And here's a nice, though a bit dated, article about building 'normal' websites in GWT: http://www.canoo.com/blog/2007/03/13/building-a-regular-website-with-the-google-web-toolkit/

I'm not sure, however, that this use of GWT is where it really shines.  One downside is a lot of javascript parsing on every page load.  Code splitting can help with that, some.